# How to add labels to auto complete dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jquery` `autocomplete` drop-down for my search module.

When some one search first it shows related category for that keyword and then items. What i want is before showing categories on drop down add a label in drop down box called "categories" and for items "item"

Loading data using `json`

```
$query="SELECT b.title AS `value`, b.title AS `label`, b.id AS `cat_id`, b.metakey AS `desc`


$db->setQuery ( $query );

// Load the results as a list of associated arrays.
$results = $db->loadAssocList ();

echo json_encode ( $results );
```

Please advice.

Comment: Your description of what you seek is unclear, and would be better with decent capitalisation of your sentences, rather than looking like a poorly crafted SMS.

Comment: @Peter: what i want is to put two labels when auto complete drop down is loading .. similar like [link](http://askme.com)  website search

Comment: Have you looked at [jQuery UI Autocomplete Categories](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories)?

Answer (score 0):

Copied directly from the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
```

To incorporate it into your code,  you probably want to load your JSON through ajax,  sending a GET request to your PHP script,  then using the returned data to create the autocomplete widget (replace the source data with the response data). Something like the following:

```
$.get("http://yourURL.com",function(responseData){
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: $.parseJSON(responseData)
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks i checked it. in my case im loading data from json and mysql queries can you give me a clue how to proceed with that way

Comment: thanks , i checked the code snippet how to change the sql to get categories sepratly. i have used union statement which first one and second query results i want to add filtering option